# Android studio programming: cannot find BLE device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

The code below can only find normal bluetooth devices. However, i would like it to discover BLE devices as well. Can someone guide me on how can i edit the codes so that it will be able to find BLE Device.

Thank you!

Here are the Codes:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    public void on(View v){
        if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void off(View v){
        BA.disable();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned off" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public  void visible(View v){
        Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    public void list(View v){
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        UUID MY_UUID_STRING = UUID.fromString("D4EEC43D-DB17-403E-BDE7-E33CBA8F0A0D");

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
            uuid = bt.getUuids().toString();
            list.add(bt.getUuids().hashCode());
            if (uuid.hashCode()==(MY_UUID_STRING.hashCode())) {
                textView.setText("FOUND");
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you at least read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html